# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos(x)}+\ldots+\sqrt[n+1]{\cos(x)}-n}{(e^x -1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I determine
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos(x)}+\ldots+\sqrt[n+1]{\cos(x)}-n}{(e^x -1)^2}
$$
without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Does it equal infinity?

I know about [this remarkable limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHmhF.png) that leaves the bottom part of the equation to an $x^2$, it being 0, makes it equal to infinite if the sum above is different than 0. Am I mistaking somewhere?

Here's a photo of the exercise to make it more clear:[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhSx5.png)

Comment: $\cos(x)$ near $0$ is positive, so $\frac{1-\cos(x)^{1/(2k-1)}}{x^2}=\frac1{2k-1}\frac{1-e^{\frac1{2k-1}\ln(1+(\cos(x)-1))}}{\frac1{2k-1}\ln(1+(\cos(x)-1))}\frac{\ln(1+(\cos(x)-1))}{\cos(x)-1}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}$

Comment: It would be ideal if there were every single root in the numerator.

Comment: $\sqrt[1]{\cos(x)} = \cos(x)^{\frac11} = \cos(x)$, whereas the first term in the numerator of the given limit is $\sqrt[2]{\cos(x)} = \sqrt{\cos(x)}$.

Comment: In the numerator, are those all odd roots? Your notation is ambiguous because it's unclear if $n+1$ is odd or even.

Comment: Then if it's odd, the numerator has have $\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor$ roots that each converging to 1, so the numerator converges to $\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor - n\neq 0$ while the denominator converges to $0$. The whole limit would be $-\infty$.

Comment: Maybe but the main point is that once you subtract $n$ you're still left with a non zero constant.

Comment: A more interesting question would be if the sum was over the first $n$ roots.

Comment: Why did you reverse the edit on the root? The photo clearly shows the first term being a square root

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am just stupid, it all comes to me just now

Answer (score 1):

For limits without L'Hopital, the trick is *always* to multiply and divide by terms until you get known limits and make use of the property $\lim a_n b_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n$ when both exist. Here rewrite the limit as

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^2\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos x}+\cdots \sqrt[n+1]{\cos x} - n}{x^2}$$

The limit on the left is a known limit, which can be proven to be $1$ by squeeze theorem. Next, split up the limits on the right

$$= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos x}-1}{x^2}+\cdots+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\cos x}-1}{x^2}$$

By geometric series, we know that

$$(r-1)(1+\cdots+r^{N-1}) = r^N-1$$

So for each $k$th root of $\cos x$, multiply and divide by the geometric series up to $k-1$ (Denote each sublimit by $L_k$)

$$L_k \equiv \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[k]{\cos x}-1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1+\cdots+(\sqrt[k]{\cos x})^{k-1}}{1+\cdots+(\sqrt[k]{\cos x})^{k-1}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\cdots+(\sqrt[k]{\cos x})^{k-1}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{1+\cdots+(\sqrt[k]{\cos x})^{k-1}}$$

The limit on the left is another known limit which equals $1$, and the limit on the right has no more singularities so we are free to take the limit by continuity

$$\implies L_k = -\frac{1}{2k}$$

which means the original limit was

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1-H_{n+1}}{2}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$th Harmonic number.

Comment: According to OP, the sum is over all odd roots, not all numbers from 2 to $n+1$.

Comment: @StefanLafon OP was wrong, have look at the photo. It starts with a square root and goes up to the $n+1$th root so that there are $n$ terms.